# Superagent security vulnerability

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, square

Received a warning from GitHub that *super agent v3.5.2 had a low grade security risk*.  Superagent is a dependency that installed with the `square-connect` npm.  Should this be manually upgraded, or should it be left alone because downloaded this following the API from Square.

```
Known low severity security vulnerability detected in superagent <3.7.0 defined in package-lock.json.
package-lock.json update suggested: superagent ~> 3.7.0.
```

Application is running with the following dependencies:

```
"square-connect": "^2.20180918.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best is to open an issue on [their github](https://github.com/square/connect-javascript-sdk/issues) directly.

You can even submit a pull-request with the upgraded dependency if it passes the tests.

> Should this be manually upgraded

AFAIK there is no standard way to override a nested dependency with `npm`.
Even if you `npm install superagent@3.7.0`, it will still keep the other version as a dependency of `square-connect`.

[Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com) supports it with the `resolutions` entry in `package.json`:

```
{
  "resolutions": {
    "superagent": "3.7.0"
  }
}
```

But that won't work with `npm`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with yarn.  I tried npm audit to update it but it the response said I had to manually update.  I did reach out to square, and as of two days ago, they said they were looking into it.  I'm going to try yarn and see what happens.